# logging within map or reduce

Tags: logging, clojure

I have the following function

```
(defn save-des-to-db [f]
    (->> f
        java.io.File.
        file-seq
        rest
        (map (juxt get-bp-name #(.getCanonicalPath %)))
        (map get-des)
        (map add-bp-des-to-db)
        ))
```

Works ok but I'd like to see some progress for each "map" as it processes a large folder.

Is there a map-with-println or map-with-log function I can use?
What is the right way to go about this.

Comment: see `dorun`, `doall` `doseq`

Comment: http://onclojure.com/2009/03/04/dorun-doseq-doall/
`(dorun (map println (range 0 10)))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The purpose of `map` is to transform a sequence into another by applying a function to every item. It is lazy, which means that it's not guaranteed to apply the function until you actually need a given item. In your case you're not doing anything with the sequence, so there's no guarantee that your elements are even saved. Therefore your function should not be called `save-des-to-db`, a more appropriate name would be `build-des-records`. I would leave out the `add-bp-des-to-db` part, and write (perhaps in a different function):

```
(doseq [f folders]
   (println "adding folder" f)
   (add-bp-des-to-db f))
```

`doseq` executes the body repeatedly, for side effects. (See the link about doseq, dorun and doall in edbond's comment)